# Carousel Recycler View Android Kotlin

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-viewpager

I'm developing a mobile application in Kotlin and XML and I'd like to create the page shown in the image below.[What I want to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JqdS.png)

I tried CarouselRecyclerview from Material Design 3, but I couldn't get the spacing between the views right.

Comment: This is ```Viewpager``` not a ```RecyclerView```. You can make  use of ```ViewPager```  for this carousel